# Delete a resource created with scaffold in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold, dbmigrate

How can I delete a resource created with the scaffold command in Ruby on Rails? If I try to overwrite it, I have problems to migrate because the table already exists!

Answer (score 1):

First you should rollback your migration:

```
rake db:rollback
```

Then to undo a scaffold in Rails use the following command:

```
rails destroy scaffold YourScaffold
```

Comment: But then I have still problems if i wanna create a new resource with the same name, because i can't do migration 'cause the table wasn't dropped

Comment: you'll need to roll back the migration that creates the database table, using `rake db:rollback`, before you destroy the scaffold.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do when running into the same problem during development.

I'd first destroy the scaffolded model by running

`rails d scaffold ScaffoldName`

I'd then drop the database to destroy the previous migrations.

**Take note: Dropping your database in production is never a good choice. I only do database dropping when in development and when I don't have any data to test with yet.  If ever I have data, I put them in a `seeds.rb` file and then I seed the db**

To drop the database and remove all previous migrations:

`rake db:drop`

To restore your old migrations before the faulty scaffold, you then do:

`rake db:migrate`

If you have a seeds.rb for prepopulating your database:

`rake db:seed`